# Since the transition from Google Chat to Hangouts, I don't see chat messages in Gmail. Can I restore those?

Tags: google-hangouts

Since the transition at the end of [June 2017](https://gsuiteupdates.googleblog.com/2017/03/updates-in-g-suite-to-streamline-hangouts-and-gmail.html), my previously displayed chat contacts in the desktop Gmail interface have not appeared. Now, I am presented with a large empty space that the contacts list used to occupy that invites me to make a call:

---

### [image: Lack of chat contacts]

I can utilize https://hangouts.google.com/ and Hangouts on my mobile device works as expected. However, I utilize the desktop client for a majority of the day.

Is there a way I can restore my chat contacts to this side bar in Gmail on my desktop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Andy,  At the bottom of the Gmail window you have icons that toggle the Hangout on of off...

Click on the hangouts to turn back on...
[image]